# how to insert a _single_ picture into a stream

Tags: video-editor

How can I insert a *single* picture into a stream to be seen for a specific seconds? 
There is abundant info in ffmpeg man, but I do not want to become a movie magician, just solve an urgent task. Please drop me a sample command line. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a) Convert the stream into WMV format

b) Split the stream where you wish to insert the picture

c) Convert said picture into WMV format

d) Do

```
cat before.wmv picture.wmv after.wmv > combined.wmv
```

e) If you intend to broadcast it, make sure you do not violate 27 C.F.R. sec, 5.65 (h) (1988) which bans broadcasting subliminal content, or any local regulation. That's the only Federal ban on subliminals I could find.

Comment: Thanks, but I am talking inserting a _picture_, not a stream. What is more, my question included timing as well.

Comment: Convert the picture into a stream is required, for x frames where x is the number of frames you want. You could create a one-frame WMV if you just want the picture to appear for 1/30 of a second (assuming you want the standard framerate); for two seconds, make it 60 frames.  

The Format Junkie app http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-convert-image-audio-and-video-formats-on-ubuntu.html will help with creating a WMV from one or more PNG files.